# html2canvas - onrendered is not working at all

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas, xhtml2pdf

Here goes my code,

```
var pdf = function() {
        console.log(12);
            var form = $('.container');
            html2canvas(form, {
              onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var pdf1 = new jsPDF();
                var marginLeft=20;
                var marginRight=20
                pdf1.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"),"jpeg",marginLeft,marginRight)
                var data =pdf1.output("datauristring");
                console.log(data);  
              }
            });
    };
```

HTML code is

```
<div class="container">
                Sample Text
            </div>
```

In index.html -

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

I am calling the pdf() method on an action, I am sure the pdf() method is called but not onrendered.
I have tried similar SO response for the html2canvas issue, still i'm not sure why I am not able to make the onrendered working. It is not getting called at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue,

jspdf.min.js is not working with html2canvas.
Instead of jspdf.min.js load jspdf.debug.js. It works fine

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

If you load jspdf.mi.js BEFORE html2canvas.js it works. :)

Comment: don't do it in the Answer content ,it isn't useful ,please put this content in comments